# Linker PIC error when statically linking a library built with PIC enabled

Tags: c++, cmake, rust, g++

I'm building a library (`libproj`) using g++-9 and CMake (on Xenial, on Travis), so I can statically link it in a Rust crate. My `build.rs` sets up and runs CMake with the following config:

```
cmake proj-7.0.1
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON
-DBUILD_TESTING=OFF
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++11 -fPIC"
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=[path snipped]/out
-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-9
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++-9
-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64
-DCMAKE_ASM_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-9
```

[Which builds and installs `libproj` successfully](https://travis-ci.org/github/georust/proj-sys/jobs/688453592#L2197).

I then tell cargo to statically link it:

```
cargo:root=[path snipped]/out
cargo:rustc-link-search=native=[path snipped]/out/lib
cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=proj
```

However, the link step fails, saying I can't use relocation in a shared object:

```
note: /usr/bin/ld: [path snipped]/out/lib/libproj.a(4D_api.cpp.o): relocation
R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a
shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

[path snipped]/out/lib/libproj.a(4D_api.cpp.o): error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've also tried to build `libproj` as a static lib by setting `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` to `OFF` as per the [install instructions](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/blob/master/docs/source/install.rst), but that hasn't had any effect.

UPDATE:

I've managed to enable PIC for g++ (by default it's only enabled for gcc)

```
running: "cmake" "-Wdev" "--debug-output" "[snipped]/proj-7.0.1" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fPIC" "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=[snipped]/out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64" "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-9" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++-9" "-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64" "-DCMAKE_ASM_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-9" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" "-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON"
```

Resulting in the following g++-9 invocation, which includes `-fPIC`:

```
/usr/bin/g++-9  -DCURL_ENABLED -DMUTEX_pthread -DPROJ_LIB=\"/[snip]/proj\" -DTIFF_ENABLED -I/[snip]/src -I/[snip]/include -I/[snip]/src -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu  -fPIC -g -fvisibility=hidden   -Wall -Wextra -Wswitch -Wshadow -Wunused-parameter -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat -Wformat-security -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/proj.dir/aasincos.cpp.o -c /[snip]/proj/proj-7.0.1/src/aasincos.cpp
```

However, I know get a completely different error (thousands of lines), that looks like my static library hasn't been correctly linked to the c++11 stdlib:

[Error](https://travis-ci.org/github/georust/proj-sys/jobs/689666810#L3033):
`undefined reference to std::allocator<char>::allocator()`

UPDATE 2:

I've managed to remove the `-nodefaultlibs` flag from `ld`. The latest g++ invocation:

```
/usr/bin/g++-9   -I/[snipped]/src -I/[snipped]/include -I/[snipped]/src -isystem /[snipped]/include -isystem /[snipped]/googletest  -fPIC -g -fvisibility=hidden   -Wall -Wextra -Wswitch -Wshadow -Wunused-parameter -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat -Wformat-security -pthread -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/proj_context_test.dir/proj_context_test.cpp.o -c /[snipped]/proj_context_test.cpp
```

And I've managed to add `lstdc++` to the linker invocation:

```
"cc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-m64" "-L" "/[snip]/lib" "/home/travis/build/georust/proj-sys/target/debug/deps/proj_sys-95cbd73f2c3f0bde.20tasg77xuhsj5z6.rcgu.o" "/home/travis/build/georust/proj-sys/target/debug/deps/proj_sys-95cbd73f2c3f0bde.57y4784ihm3qw715.rcgu.o" "-o" "/[snip]/deps/proj_sys-95cbd73f2c3f0bde" "/home/travis/build/georust/proj-sys/target/debug/deps/proj_sys-95cbd73f2c3f0bde.3kiafs23968zh4mj.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro" "-Wl,-znow" "-L" "/home/travis/build/georust/proj-sys/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/travis/build/georust/proj-sys/target/debug/build/proj-sys-aff2ac9d43b77886/out/lib" "-L" "/home/travis/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-lsqlite3" "-lcurl" "-ltiff" "-lstdc++" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "-Wl,--whole-archive" "-lproj" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" [trimmed rlib details] "-Wl,--end-group" "/home/travis/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-2541f1e09df1c67d.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-ldl" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lgcc_s" "-lc" "-lm" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lutil" "-lutil"
```

But the [undefined reference error](https://travis-ci.org/github/georust/proj-sys/jobs/689988539#L2664) remains.

Answer (score 3):

As I can see from your example, you have quotation marks around `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and do not have ones around `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`. It looks odd.

I have built `libgproj` myself with `cmake` + your flags and with `make VERBOSE=1`.

I can see, that C-files compiled without `fPIC`, `m64` and `fdata-sections`. I suppose, that the cause is in the quotation marks around `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`. I saw your log in Travis, and there is configuration for `cmake` from `cargo`:

```
"cmake" "/home/travis/build/georust/proj-sys/PROJSRC/proj/proj-7.0.1" "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON" "-DBUILD_TESTING=OFF" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -fPIC" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/travis/build/georust/proj-sys/target/debug/build/proj-sys-03a5fe6428bb060a/out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64" "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-9" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++-9" "-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64" "-DCMAKE_ASM_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-9"
```

Note, that `-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` escaped with their values, and not values by itself. I suppose, that these options become in the shell:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64 -DCVMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -fPIC
```

I have tried this command, without quotation marks and cmake just ignored unknown options. So it will not fail.

I suggest you to add cmake option `-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON` to cmake configuration or `VERBOSE=1` to the `make` options, if you can, and then you can see real compile options passed to gcc in Travis.

You will see somethig like this:

```
[ 19%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/proj.dir/wkt1_generated_parser.c.o
cd [some path]/PROJ/cmake_build/src && /usr/bin/cc -DCURL_ENABLED -DMUTEX_pthread 
-DPROJ_LIB=\"/usr/local/share/proj\" -DTIFF_ENABLED -I[some path]PROJ/src -I[some 
path]/PROJ/include -I[some path]/PROJ/cmake_build/src  -O3 -DNDEBUG - 
fvisibility=hidden   -Wall -Wextra -Wswitch -Wshadow -Wunused-parameter -Wmissing- 
declarations -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-prototypes -std=c99 -o 
CMakeFiles/proj.dir/wkt1_generated_parser.c.o   -c [some 
path]/PROJ/src/wkt1_generated_parser.c
```

Conclusion:

1. You can try adding verbosity to see real compile options.
2. You can try to escape options properly, if it's necessary after first step.

Also I want to note, that `SHARED_BUILD_LIBS=ON` in my test forbids building static lib, which you want to link. When I set shared libs building setting option to `OFF`, static lib was built.

Comment: OK, this was useful! I've managed to pass an `-fPIC` invocation to `g++-9`, and explicitly build a static library, but I now have a completely different set of errors that look like the c++11 stdlib isn't being correctly linked.

Comment: Try to use define -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0

There is ABI change in C++11. Usually such errors related to std::string.

This define needed when you links libraries or binaries with different CXX_11_ABI.

Comment: Okay, I see in Travis.

Problem is that libproj needs libstdc++ as runtime. But I can see in your Travis, that you uses `-nodefaultlibs`. This option disables linking with all standard libs, so you have thousands unresolved references of all standard lib functions.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what is building here:`... sys/target/debug/deps/proj_sys-6b64516d7397f682.31egxm16liuikgs0.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro" "-Wl,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L"  ... `

At the end I can see `"-lgcc_s"`

So you linking gcc_s explicitly, but not linking libstdc++. You can try to staticaly linking libstdc++ to libproj with -static-libstdc++.

Usually this is not great idea, but I don't know at this moment how to build rust code with C++ library. If there is way to link libstdc++ to rust code, you can try.

Comment: I think, that if you can manually add gcc_s to linking, you can also add libstdc++ with option -lstdc++.